# Magento 1.702 fatal error after migration to new server

Tags: php, magento-1.7

Just finished migrating a Magento website to a new server. Using the following steps:

```
-Backup the database in the backend
-Import the database on new server
-Copy all files from old server to new server
-Set correct file permissions
-Update /app/etc/local.xml
-Update secure and unsecure base_url in database
-Remove cache and session files
```

The website itself works fine, but it seems to give a fatal error on the order button now (see [screenshot of source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE7DC.jpg))

This is the block of code the error refers to:

```
/**
 * Product type instance factory
 *
 * @param   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
 * @param   bool $singleton
 * @return  Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract
 */
public static function factory($product, $singleton = false)
{
    $types = self::getTypes();
    $typeId = $product->getTypeId();

    if (!empty($types[$typeId]['model'])) {
        $typeModelName = $types[$typeId]['model'];
    } else {
        $typeModelName = self::DEFAULT_TYPE_MODEL;
        $typeId = self::DEFAULT_TYPE;
    }

    if ($singleton === true) {
        $typeModel = Mage::getSingleton($typeModelName);
    }
    else {
        $typeModel = Mage::getModel($typeModelName);
        $typeModel->setProduct($product);
    }
    $typeModel->setConfig($types[$typeId]); /**this is line 80**/
    return $typeModel;
}
```

I also tried to make a fresh install and copy the needed files, but that did not work either.

This is my first time working with Magento, and searching online for a solution did not bring up anything useful to me. Could anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: This might possibly be related to dodgy product data imported into the database? What this method is doing is pretty basic. Can you debug `$types` and `$typdId`, and output the entity ID of the product in question?

Comment: Sorry for my compete noobness on this subject, but how do i do that?

Comment: Put var dumps into the code